# How to include hashtag (#) in PHP parameter URL?

Tags: php, html, parameters, request, hashtag

I'm making a PHP request for a login handler and it looks like this: https://example.com/test.php?username=test123&password=hiuhsda3#24

But I want to keep the hashtag in the password or username and everything after that. How can I do this?

The result for the password that I'd get is hiuhsda3

Comment: It's not recommended to pass the user name and password on the URL - https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/147188/is-it-bad-practice-to-use-get-method-as-login-username-password-for-administrato

Comment: I'm doing this so I can authorize through my c++ program and use the same details. The forum software I'm using is Invision Community. What other ways can I do this?

Comment: `urlencode` comes to mind ... but... don't do this. Find a better way to pass a body to whatever endpoint you are doing. We cannot answer that here as there is far too little information to go on.

Comment: What if I were to encrypt the username and password and then decrypt through the PHP script?

Comment: Encrypt and dont use '#' because is a URL anchor

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Its never a good idea to pass password in url.
use Post Request

Comment: Thanks, I'm not good with PHP, I forgot about POST requests

Comment: Its Okay, You will learn when you will make mistakes.
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_get_post.htm

Read this if you have any doubts with GET and POST Requests.